# Counting the number of different values in a MySQL column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

I'm partially familiar with the `COUNT` function, but I'm a little stumped as to how I can apply it to this specific situation. Suppose I have a table with one of the columns containing the following values:

```
apples
apples
apples
oranges
oranges
bananas
```

These values can be added by users, so I never know what values may end up in this column, but there will always be duplicates. What I first want to do is to display them in a HTML table, so that each row will represent one particular value, and each adjacent cell shows the number of duplicate values. Using the example data above, the expected output in a HTML table generated by PHP would be:

```
|Fruits     | Amount   |
|-----------|----------|
|apples     | 3        |
|oranges    | 2        |
|bananas    | 1        |
```

At this stage, I know that I have to use the `COUNT` function in SQL, and through PHP, I need to run some sort of foreach loop, but beyond that, I'm not sure how to proceed.

EDIT: Changed the data. Hopefully it makes a little more sense

Comment: Sidenote: If `Value name` is your actual column name, try not using spaces between words. Either use underscores or backticks around column names when querying.

Comment: Retrieve the row values to a PHP array, then use [array_count_values()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) or use SQL `COUNT` aggregation with `GROUP BY`

Comment: Sorry, I was just trying to keep it simple with the naming

Comment: @MarkBaker: Would that be in the way that I mentioned in the comments under Noah's answer?

Comment: @Hiigaran - your simplification of the naming is actually making your question ambiguous; it would probably help if you showed a real-world example of what you have in your database, and what you want to achieve

Comment: I haven't populated the database yet. I can edit the question to see if I can remove some of that ambiguity. EDIT: Is that better?

Comment: Then @aldux answer is the syntax you need in your SELECT statement, where the column name is the column you're labelling `Fruits`

Comment: Alright, I'll give that a shot the next time I have server access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT [column_name], COUNT([column_name])
FROM [table_name]
GROUP BY [column_name];
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `GROUP BY valueName;` to the end of your query.

Comment: That would imply that I know what the value would be, wouldn't it? If we say that there is a valueX in the database, I wouldn't be able to code for that specific value, unless I knew it existed...Right?

Comment: No. The query will fetch all records, grouped by the valueName.

Comment: use the column name (which you've so specifically noted as `Value name`

Comment: This is pretty much what you get when you don't actually post any queries or DDL

Comment: I'm still not understanding this. You use GROUP BY, and then what? Are they stored in an array for PHP when it is returned, that I can then use foreach($returnedArray as $values) { /*SQL query to count rows where 'Value name' column = $values*/ }?

Comment: crazy idea, try it and see what happens

Comment: It sounds like you need a firmer grasp on the data constructs and flow control in PHP and how to handle data passed from MySQL... Among other things. However, as you've asked for how to group the count of the results based on duplicate values, this modification to your query (or see @aldux's answer for a more complete spoon-feeding) will get you the data that you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select `column name`, count(*) from `table1`
group by `column name`
```